# RestEasy proxy framework file upload

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, jax-rs, resteasy

Does anyone know how to send request and upload file with ResteasyClient and  proxy framework?

I know way to send request with MultipartFormDataOutput

```
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();

ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("http://.../upload");

MultipartFormDataOutput mdo = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
mdo.addFormData("file", new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/file.txt")),
    MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
GenericEntity<MultipartFormDataOutput> entity = new GenericEntity<MultipartFormDataOutput>(mdo) {};

Response r = target.request().post( Entity.entity(entity, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE));
```

I want to send this request using a proxy framework, but it does not work :(

```
FileUploadForm fileForm = new FileUploadForm();
//add file

ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
client.target(getHostUrl()).proxy(ProxyApi.class).uploadFile(fileForm);

@Path("/")
public interface ProxyApi {    

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/upload")
    String uploadFile(@MultipartForm FileUploadForm form);
}


import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.providers.multipart.PartType;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;

public class FileUploadForm {

    @FormParam("pos")
    @PartType("text/plain")
    public File image;

    //Get and set method 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if the type of the field is `InputStream` instead of `File`, e.g.:

```java
FileUploadForm fileForm = new FileUploadForm();
fileForm.setImage(new FileInputStream("path/to/file"));

// ...

public class FileUploadForm {

    @FormParam("pos")
    @PartType("text/plain")
    public InputStream image;

    //Get and set method 

}
```